# The Theatre problem

Tags: probability-theory

Been experiencing some difficulty with a probability theory problem. Below are the question and my thoughts so far.

Two movie theaters compete for the business of a total of 1000 customers
at the same time. Assume that each customer randomly chooses between
these two movie theaters independently. Let $N$ denote the number of seats
in each theater. Calculate the probability of turning away at least one
customer because of a full house in terms of $N$.

Attempted solution

The whole problem depends on the nature of $N$ in relation to $1000$.

If $N < 500$, then $2N < 1000$, in which case, at least one customer will be turned away so that the probability value will be $1$.

If $N\geq 1000$, the clearly nobody gets turned away which implies that the probability of someone getting turned away is $0$.

Suppose $500\leq N <1000$. Let $X$ be the number of customers who chose theatre 1. Since each customer has two possible choices, the probability of a customer choosing theatre 1 is $0.5$. Notice that $X$ is a Binomial R.V with $n = 1000$ and $p =0.5$. Since $X$ is the number of customers who chose theatre 1, then $1000- X$ will be the number of customers who chose theatre 2. Also, $1000-X$ is a Binomial R.V with the same parameters as $X$.

The challenge I am experiencing right now is how to express the probability that at least $1$ customer gets turned away in terms of $N$. Is it the same as finding $P(\{X>N\}\cup\{1000-X>N\})$? If yes, how do I express this probability value in terms of $N$ only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $500 \le N < 1000$.

$X \sim Bin(1000, 0.5)$, we want to know the probability that

\begin{align}P(\{X > N\} \cup\{1000-X>N\}) &=P(X>N) + P(X<1000-N)-P(N < X < 1000-N) \\&=P(X > N) + P(X < 1000-N) \\
&= 1-P(1000-N \le X \le N) \\
&= 1- \sum_{i=N}^{1000-N} \binom{1000}{i}\frac1{2^{1000}}\\
&= 2\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\binom{1000}{i}\frac{1}{2^{1000}}\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You are expected to use the [normal approximation to the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation).  For $1000$ customers the number that choose theater $1$ will be approximately a normal distribution with mean $\frac 12\cdot 1000=500$ and standard deviation $\sqrt {1000\cdot \frac 12 \cdot 12}=\sqrt {250}\approx 15.81$.  Now you can use your $z-$score table to compute the chance that at least $N$ customers choose theater $1$.  If you want to report it as a formula it comes out in terms of the error function.